# How to remove Children Nodes and add them to parent Node by removing current Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to organize a JSON data. Here is my JSON:

```
let all = [
    {
        id: "n1",
        name: "Hipokrat",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n2",
                name: "Edward Janner",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "n9",
                        name: "Edison, Thomas",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "n3",
        name: "William Harvey",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n10",
                name: "Lister, Joseph",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "n11",
                        name: "Kant, Immanuel",
                        children: [
                            {
                                id: "n15",
                                name: "Rawls, John"
                            },
                            {
                                id: "n46",
                                name: "More, Thomas",
                            },
                            {
                                id: "n47",
                                name: "Galen",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "n12",
                name: "Smith, Adam",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "n48",
        name: "Osler, William",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n51",
                name: "Louis Pasteur",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "n52",
        name: "John Hunter",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n53",
                name: "Freud, Sigmund",
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

At here, I want to find the node with "n10" id and move them to the ancestor node which is "William Harvey" and with "n3" id. We should add these to children array.

So I want this result:

```
let all = [
    {
        id: "n1",
        name: "Hipokrat",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n2",
                name: "Edward Janner",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "n9",
                        name: "Edison, Thomas",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "n3",
        name: "William Harvey",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n11",
                name: "Kant, Immanuel",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "n15",
                        name: "Rawls, John"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "n46",
                        name: "More, Thomas",
                    },
                    {
                        id: "n47",
                        name: "Galen",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "n12",
                name: "Smith, Adam",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "n48",
        name: "Osler, William",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n51",
                name: "Louis Pasteur",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "n52",
        name: "John Hunter",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n53",
                name: "Freud, Sigmund",
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Here is my try:

```js
let all = [
    {
        id: "n1",
        name: "Hipokrat",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n2",
                name: "Edward Janner",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "n9",
                        name: "Edison, Thomas",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "n3",
        name: "William Harvey",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n11",
                name: "Kant, Immanuel",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "n15",
                        name: "Rawls, John"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "n46",
                        name: "More, Thomas",
                    },
                    {
                        id: "n47",
                        name: "Galen",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "n12",
                name: "Smith, Adam",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "n48",
        name: "Osler, William",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n51",
                name: "Louis Pasteur",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "n52",
        name: "John Hunter",
        children: [
            {
                id: "n53",
                name: "Freud, Sigmund",
            }
        ]
    }
];

function isObject(variable){
    if ( typeof variable === 'object' && !Array.isArray(variable) && variable !== null) {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}

function isArray(variable){
    if(!isObject(variable) && Array.isArray(variable)){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}

function process(all, value, indexes = "", foundAndChildren = false) {
    if(foundAndChildren){
        return foundAndChildren;
    }
    if(isArray(all)){                               // is Array
        console.log("-> Children size: " + all.length);
        console.log("-PASSED WITH 1");
        console.log("-----------------");
        console.log("");
        
        all.forEach(subElement => {
            return process(subElement, value);
        });
    } else if(isObject(all)){                       // is object
        if(all["id"] == value){                     // Match
            console.log("#########");
            console.log(all.id);
            console.log(all.name);
            console.log("--PASSED WITH 2");
            let children = [];
            if(all["children"] != undefined){
                children = all.children
            }
            let res = {
                id: value,
                indexes: indexes,
                children: children
            };
            
            console.log(res);
            return res;
        } else {
            console.log(all.name);
            console.log("--PASSED WITH 3");
            console.log("");
            if(isArray(all["children"])) {       // is object but has children
                console.log("->" + all.name);
                console.log("Children size:" + all.children.length);
                console.log("--PASSED WITH 4");
                console.log("");
                all["children"].forEach(elementOfChildren => {
                    return process(elementOfChildren, value);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(process(all, "n10"));
```

And here is the playground: https://playcode.io/823402/

Comment: I don't get it. Your attempt doesn't even mention `n10`. Is there something more general you want?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add run code.

Comment: To be clear, by "I want to find the node with "n10" id and move them to the ancestor node" you mean moving n10's *children* into n10's parent's children?

Comment: @weltschmerz exactly!

Comment: but what happen with Lister, Joseph ? No child -- no records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function replaceNode(jsonData, id) {
    function replaceChildren(o, id) {
        for (let key in o) {
            const object = o[key]
            if (object.id == id) {
                if (object.children && object.children.length > 0) {
                    o.splice(key, 1, ...object.children)
                    return true
                } else throw `id: ${id} has no children`
            } else {
                if (object.children && object.children.length > 0) {
                    const found = replaceChildren(object.children, id)
                    if (found) return found
                }
            }
        }
    }
    const o = [...jsonData]
    replaceChildren(o, id)
    return o
}
```

and then pass the json data and the node id

```
const output = replaceNode(all, 'n10')
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Because it returns `undefined`.

Comment: @sundowatch The function was only modifying the original array without returning anything. I just edited it so now it should return a new array instead.